# Does device drivers use Kernel logical address space or Kernel virtual address space?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, devices

If possible, can you point to documentation or describe the kernel space memory layout?

When a device driver instantiates a variable does that variable live in the kernel space or does it live in user space with special permissions?

Answer (score 3):

The kernel space memory layout is [documented in the kernel, for x86_64 at least](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html). On many architectures, this includes a direct physical mapping, with a fixed offset which doesn’t vary over one kernel instance’s lifetime. Since the kernel code runs on the CPU, using the MMU (on MMU-equipped architectures), all the addresses referenced by running code (for variable pointers, stacks etc.) are addresses understandable by the MMU, *i.e.* virtual addresses, normally allocated outside the direct physical mapping.

Variables in device drivers are mapped in kernel space by default. A device driver can also make data available from user space, in a variety of ways — `sysfs`, `procfs`, mapped to user space in [the vDSO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/abi-stable.html#vdso)...

Comment: As far as I know, the kernel space is split into two types of addressing - 1) logical addressing (1-to-1 mapping) and 2) kernel virtual addressing. I assume that the kernel space heap and stack use kernel virtual addressing, but that's what I'm wondering about. Thank you for the documentation links and your time!

Comment: Don’t you mean physical addressing? IME “logical addressing” is a synonym with “virtual addressing”.